# Generator yield still works while omitting .next()

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, generator

Can `yield` be evaluated even if it is not followed by `.next()`?

I have a piece of code that will be saved in Firebase. Since the code will generate data contention error, I have wrapped the function generator that will be saved in a collection to `Promise.all()`. It works as expected, it's faster than the previous code I made, and seems there's no data contention I encountered. The file I uploaded has same id (100 same id) thus it change same collection over time.

My question is, how does it happen that `yield` still works even I did not call `.next()`?

```
function * sampleGenerator(payload) {
  yield utils.toCollection(payload.id)
}


async function save() {
    for(let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ... code here
    const payload = {id: "", data: "", others: ""}
    await Promise.all(sampleGenerator(payload))
  }
}
```

All data is saved in Firebase as expected here.

Answer (score 1):

The Generator returns an *iterable*, and `Promise.all` accepts an *iterable*, so this works...but it might not be doing what you expect.

Generator functions, once called, [return an Iterable object as on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator):

> The **`Generator object`** is returned by a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and it conforms to both the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol) and the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterator_protocol).

`Promise.all` [accepts an iterable object as on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

> The **`Promise.all()`** method takes an iterable of promises as an input, and returns a single [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that resolves to an array of the results of the input promises.

However, you should be aware of these aspects:

- Because Promise.all will internally and synchronously turn your generator-based iterable into an array, it's not really more useful than just having a simple function that returns a collection.
- `function * sampleGenerator(payload)` currently yields your collection as a single yielded item, not the [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) syntax that would yield items from your collection (generated here by `utils.toCollection`) one by one. If your `sampleGenerator` collection contained Promises instead, your `Promise.all` would receive something like `Promise.all([[promise1, ...]])` (i.e. an array Promise.all creates that holds a single element, the collection you yield) and not wait for the results. If you `yield` Promises one by one, or `yield*` a collection of Promises, you'd see `Promise.all([promise1, ...])` and correctly get back `[result1, ...]`.
- One typical way of combining generators and promises is with [async generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncGenerator), which might have more sequential ordering than you want here, but is worth knowing for the sake of being able to answer "why not".
- If your `await Promise.all` is being returned from `save`, and you don't `await` anything else inside `save`, then the `async` aspect of the function isn't getting you much aside from documentation (and putting `save` on the stack trace). It would be mostly equivalent just to return the `Promise.all` promise directly and remove the `async` keyword from the function.